# Scraping a dynamic website with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im fairly new to BeautifullSoup and I already did some scraping (on websites that agree to it in their TOS) with it in the past, everything worked juste fine.

But then I came across this one website. I could see the datas I want in it's source code but when I would display the content like I used to do on other websites, there were none of the datas I was looking for. I noticed "script" tags in the source code and a friend of mine told me that it may be "dynamic pages" that needs a browser to display it.

The website im trying to scrape is https://u.gg/lol/champions/aatrox/runes
And what I want to extract is the percentages bellow every icon in the lower tables + the icon names thereselves

Bellow is a simplified form of the code I ran but it works exactly the same way and the problem is the same :
When I run it it doesn't show what I see in the source code of the page (which is what I want).

```py
import asyncio
import os 

import requests

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

import json

# ====================

def Scrape(url):

    req = Request(url, headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    uClient = uReq(req)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    return page_soup

champ_keystone_url = "https://u.gg/lol/champions/aatrox/runes"
champ_keystone_page_content = Scrape(champ_keystone_url)

print(champ_keystone_page_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded dynamically using Ajax from their Api. This code will print various runes and their percentages.

However, the data is various levels deep (the numbers mean Rank (Iron, Platinum...), Position (Top, Jungle, ...), etc.) I don't know the game, so I cannot interpret them correctly (maybe you can try solution with `selenium`):

```
import requests
import json


champion_url = 'https://static.u.gg/assets/lol/riot_static/10.14.1/data/en_US/champion/Aatrox.json'
runes_url = 'https://stats2.u.gg/lol/1.1/table/runes/10_14/ranked_solo_5x5/{key}/1.4.0.json'
rune_names_url = 'https://static.u.gg/assets/lol/riot_static/10.14.1/data/en_US/runesReforged.json'

rune_names = requests.get(rune_names_url).json()

runes = {}
for val in rune_names:
    for s in val['slots']:
        for r in s['runes']:
            runes[r['id']] = (r['name'], r['longDesc'])

champion_data = requests.get(champion_url).json()
key = champion_data['data']['Aatrox']['key']
runes_data = requests.get(runes_url.format(key=key)).json()

def transform_runes_data(dct):
    for k, v in list(dct.items()):
        if isinstance(v, list) and len(v) == 2:
            dct[runes[int(k)][0]] = (v[0] / v[1]) * 100
            del dct[k]
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            transform_runes_data(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for vv in v:
                transform_runes_data(vv)

transform_runes_data(runes_data)

print(json.dumps(runes_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "1": {
        "1": {
            "3": [
                {
                    "Conqueror": 0.0
                },
                {
                    "Last Stand": 0.0,
                    "Legend: Tenacity": 0.0,
                    "Triumph": 0.0
                },
                {
                    "Second Wind": 0.0,
                    "Revitalize": 0.0
                }
            ],
            "4": [
                {
                    "Conqueror": 36.36363636363637,
                    "Electrocute": 0.0,
                    "Grasp of the Undying": 100.0
                },
                {
                    "Ghost Poro": 0.0,
                    "Ravenous Hunter": 0.0,
                    "Taste of Blood": 0.0,
                    "Last Stand": 36.36363636363637,
                    "Conditioning": 100.0,
                    "Demolish": 100.0,
                    "Revitalize": 100.0,
                    "Legend: Alacrity": 25.0,
                    "Legend: Tenacity": 38.88888888888889,
                    "Triumph": 36.36363636363637
                },
                {
                    "Ravenous Hunter": 28.57142857142857,
                    "Taste of Blood": 28.57142857142857,
                    "Unflinching": 0.0,
                    "Magical Footwear": 66.66666666666666,
                    "Cosmic Insight": 66.66666666666666,
                    "Conditioning": 0.0,
                    "Second Wind": 45.45454545454545,
                    "Demolish": 100.0,
                    "Overgrowth": 18.181818181818183,
                    "Revitalize": 45.45454545454545,
                    "Bone Plating": 36.36363636363637
                }

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess it solve every problem I had, I'll juste have to understand and work around this but it is greatly helping, thanks so much

Comment: There is only one of the two percentages do you know why ?
Also it's a bit a pain to understand what are each keys of the dict, do you have a way to know easily ?

Comment: @Deltix Yes, exactly. That's why I proposed to look at `selenium` - it will run the page in normal browser and execute JavaScript - so you can then grab the final values.

Comment: Yes I might go for selenium, i'll just keep trying with the json for a bit cuz it's still interesting

Comment: @Deltix I think in the Json values are more information than is presented on the screen. So maybe you'll find something interesting :)

Comment: Yes but it's strange that there is only the winrate and not the pickrate :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but sometimes there is a better solution than using heavy selenium.

This [request module](https://github.com/psf/requests-html) for python comes with JS support (in the background it is still chromium) and you can still use beautifulsoup like normal.
Though, sometimes if you have to click elements or sth, I guess selenium is the only option.